# .NET Core String Interpolation Bug in Razor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, compiler-errors, string-interpolation

I don't understand why this will not compile when typed out in a .cshtml/Razor page:

```
@($"{"\""}") // <-- does not work

@($"{"'"}") // <-- does not work

@($"{"a"}") // <-- works
```

The error states:

> RZ1000: Unterminated string literal. Strings that start with a quotation mark (") must be terminated before the end of the line. However, strings that start with @ and a quotation mark (@") can span multiple lines.
>
> CS1002: ; expected
>
> CS1513: } expected

It appears that non-quote characters work fine, but a double-quote or single-quote character breaks Razor's ability to parse the interpolated string, even when the quote character is escaped.

All the examples work fine in a plain .cs file:

```
public sealed class Test
{
    public string x = $"{"\""}";
    public string y = $"{"'"}";
    public string z = $"{"a"}";
}
```

What gives?

My environment is as follows:

**.NET SDK: v7.0.102**

**.NET Runtime: v7.0.2**

**C#: v11 (preview)**

**Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit): v17.4.4**

[image]

Comment: What do you expect `@($"{"\""}")` to resolve to. Throwing away the _Razor-ness_, that's `$"{"\""}"`. If I parse it in my head, I get an interpolated string (`$"`) that starts with `{` - OK, a variable name should follow - but that's immediately followed by a double-quote. At that point, I have `$"{"`. I've finished parsing the string, the rest is garbage (and, it's an interpolated string with a danglin `{`). What am I missing

Comment: @Flydog57 I would expect it to output the single character `"` to the page. You will see that if you replace the `@($"{"\""}")` with `@($"{"a"}")` it compiles fine, and outputs `a` to the page, as expected.

Comment: @Flydog57 The braces in an interpolated string can contain any expression (although there are specific rules for ternaries because of the `:`). It compiles fine in plain C#, and resolves to a string containing a single quote https://dotnetfiddle.net/sYoTEl

Comment: @Flydog57 You should not parse it in your head... Your head has a parser error.

Comment: @Flydog57 turns out it is a bug after all, see the answer I just posted

Comment: @Charlieface turns out it is a bug after all, see the answer I just posted

Comment: @emilsteen My head has many errors. But, after 20 years in c# land, I'm surprised that I still find surprises. To me, this violates the guideline that Eric Lippert likes to talk about: _Thr principle of least surprise_

Comment: This is a bug. I will log and submit a request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug, known by the .NET guys as far back as 2015 at least.

The dotnet engineers on the dotnet/aspnetcore github page felt the work required to fix it outweighed the benefits, however:

> *Jun 3, 2015*
>
> After investigating this issue further turns out the requirements to complete this are pretty high (need to understand C# close to entirety at the Tokenizer level). Will revisit this later.

10 weeks and 2 days later...

> *Aug 14, 2015*
>
> Moving to backlog because we feel these cases are not common in MVC views, and have trivial workarounds (e.g. use string.Format() instead of string interpolation).

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4976