# C# 11 String Literal, triple quote multiline not working

Tags: c#, string, literals

I've been using the new C# string literal feature for a bit and it's been great, but for some reason in a new project .NET7.0, Blazor Server, I am getting the following error

`RZ1000 Unterminated string literal.  Strings that start with a quotation mark (") must be terminated before the end of the line.  However, strings that start with @ and a quotation mark (@") can span multiple lines`

The code looks like this:

```
    string longMessage = """
This is a long message.
It has several lines.
    Some are indented
            more than others.
Some should start at the first column.
Some have "quoted text" in them.
""";
```

[image]

This is strange because if I copy and paste into another project it works, but not this one.

Targeting .NET7 as shown below

[image]

I've also tried cleaning the project, to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: might just be a bug: [net-core-string-interpolation-bug-in-razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75430137/net-core-string-interpolation-bug-in-razor)

Comment: Not sure how that link is related @topsail. This sounds like the compiler doesn't understand that C# 11 is used to compile the source code.

Comment: Is there `<LangVersion>` tag in .csproj? Btw. You can indent the whole string to make it align with your code. The spaces to the left of the ending `"""` will be removed from all the string lines.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes no langversion tag, but there's also not in any other project where this feature is working. I did add it with preview lang but still same errors.

Comment: What Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.4.0